# Am I building the wrong entities in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ef-code-first

Goal. I have a "Gift" entity that describes what someone has to offer (babysitting, dog walking, etc) with a rating. And I want a "GiftCategory" entity that gives general category descriptive information (pets, sports, automotive, etc) for someone to search apon and then get all gift that have those categories. A "Gift" entity can have multiple "GiftCategory" entities associated with it. I want the ability to search for a category and pull out all "Gift" entities that have been created with those categories associated with them. Here is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work with the entity first approach. Maybe I need another table that connects the two entities because currently the way the two tables are connected doesn't seem correct?

Gift entity:

```
public class Gift
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GiftCategory> Categories { get; set; } // is this incorrect???
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Category entity:

```
public class GiftCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The "GiftCategory" table that gets created creates a gift_id column that links the "GiftCategory" back to a gift (not what I want)!!!!

It seems like I would need to create a entity that connects the two entities? Something like:

```
public class ConnectGifts
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GiftId{ get; set; }
    public string GiftCategoryID{ get; set; }
}
```

This way I can have multiple categories for a Gift, but the thing I don't understand is with entity first I really don't need this entity I just need what would be this table to get/query the "GiftCategory" entities for ids then get the gift ids to get all the gifts. So it seems like creating this entity is overkill? Is there a way to do it without creating a third table/entity ("ConnectGifts") with code first? Or am I not understanding that all entities are tables and all tables are entities? I'm also using linq-to-sql for all querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a `many-to-many` relationship and can be defined as:

```
public class Gift  
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GiftCategory> Categories { get; set; } // is this incorrect???
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}

public class GiftCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Gift> Gifts { get; set; }
}
```

So each has a collection of the other. `Gift` has many `Categories` and `Category` had many `Gifts`. You could use a `bridge` table like you've done with `ConnectGifts` but it's not necessary with EF. Using just `Gift` and `GiftCategory`, EF will actually create the bridge table for you.

Comment: but I don't want to associate GiftCategories with any Gifts! If I create a GiftCategory with a collection of Gifts then won't it tie GiftCategories with specific gifts? Categories are just categories. I'm not sure that's what I want. I don't want GiftCategories tied with any specific Gifts, but I do want Gifts tied to GiftCategories, I don't think!!

Comment: EF creates the bridge table with the ids in it, but how would I query for all gifts given a category using linq-to-sql if I don't have a entity with the bridge data in it?

Comment: You don't need to worry about it. EF handles all of this for you. If you wanted every gift of category `pet` you could do `var gifts = giftDbSet.Where(m => m.Category.Name == "pet").ToList()`. EF will handle all the bridge stuff for you.

Comment: Where is m => m.Category.Name coming from? is M from GiftCategories or Gift?

Comment: It's `LINQ`. The Where method allows me to pass a `lambda` in. Look around Google for those terms. They go hand-in-hand with EF. But to answer your specific question: in my example, m would be gift. The where method will loop through every gift in `giftDbSet` and return every item that meets the condition specified in the lambda. Well it doesn't actually return the items. It really just builds a query and only when I call ToList is the query executed.

Comment: It's `Linq`. The `m => m.Category.Name == "pet"` is a `lambda`. Search around Google for those terms; linq goes hand-in-hand with EF and is very useful to know. To make it clear though, there is an issue with my example. It assumed a gift could only have one category. Taking the many-to-many relationship into account, the example should actually be `m => m.Categories.Any(c => c.Name == "pet")`.